# deserialize json

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization, datacontractserializer, javascriptserializer

I am trying to call a web-service from an aspx page. The web-service returns json. I need to deserialize the json objects.

I tried to extract the string, it is of the form :

```
"{ \" d \" : [ { \" _type \" : \" Myclass:#serviceName \", ....other members..}, { ..other records ... }, {...} ] }"
```

My code is as follows :

```
    Stream receivedStream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream();
    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receivedStream, encode);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd(); // text shows the above string
```

Kindly help me what to do next. Also a refernce of some good articles on the topic would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Use JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize<YourObjectModel>(text) method; built-in the .net framework. What's weird is that this looks like a string that came from the server to the page because it encapsulates the actual data inside d. If you're sending back json to the server, there's no need for .d

Comment: Hi @frenchie, I already tried the JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize method, and it just returns null. I think it is due to that "d" thing. I even tried the DataContractJsonSerializer but to no help. I donot know how to handle the "d" in the return type class that I create.

Comment: Where is this json coming from??? If you're sending it from the page with $.ajax for instance, it should not be encapsulated in the .d property. Are you calling a web service in your code behind file? Have you tried var x = JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize<string>(text); to extract the d and then var x2 = JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<YourObjectModel>>(x); ??

Comment: yes, i am calling it from code-behind aspx.cs page. I tried to extract directly as 
 var x = (list)JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize(text);
which returned null. I will try the thing u mentioned and come back later. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is "var x = (list)JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize(text);" I think the correct syntax involves a 2-step process to first isolate the .d and second to cast to a list of object model. Can you paste the object's class definition? To deserialize to a list, it's var x2 = JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<YourObjectModel>>(x);

Comment: In my code, I have two classes : student class and allStudents class. I return a list of 'student' objects from the service as above. And regarding the two-level deserialization as you said above, when I try to deserialize it to a string first, it still shows null.

Comment: The issue has been solved. I explicitly serialized the json object in my web service which was easy to parse in the calling function, since there was no "d" thing and JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(text) worked perfectly. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an earlier .NET version and/or you want more features, check this out:

http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend: http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=deserialize+json+c%23

The first result looks like it has exactly what you need: http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c/